# CTreeCtrl disable drag and drop on specific nodes

Tags: c++, mfc, treecontrol

I there a way to disable drag and drop on specific nodes of a CTreeCtrl?

I would like to prevent dragging a node to a child of that same node within the same tree, and also to prevent dragging a node to a listview that is linked to the same node or one of it's children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just depends on how you handle the drop target in the mouse move handler.

You can not prevent the `TVN_BEGINDRAG` function. But if the item shouldn't be dragged at all, you always use `SetDropTarget(NULL)` in the mouse move handler and if dragging stops you do nothing.

When the item is allowed to be dragged, you just need to check if the target is allowed. You use `HitTest` to find the target item and you can check if it is allowed to drop here. Again use `SetDropTarget`. So the user can see what is allowed.

Another way would be to implement the Ole Drag&Drop functions [like in this sample here](http://www.ucancode.net/VC_Library_Control_Tool/OLE-DRAG-DROP-TREE-Control-CTreeCtrl-VC-Article.htm).

Comment: Yeah, I am already using the OnDragOver override to handle drop determination (for other cases), just didn't know if there was another way to "temporarily" disable dropability on specific nodes instead of figuring it out in OnDragOver as well.. I suppose in the OnDragOver, I recursively check parents of nodes of the node in the HitTest to see if it finds the dragged node (thus not allowing a parent node to be dragged to one of it's children). Was just hoping such method already existed.

Comment: I want to create the same behavior as windows explorer, which returns a DROPEFFECT_NONE in the OnDragOver when a node is dragged over any of it's children.

Comment: Than implement your own Drag&Drop like in this sampler for the list control http://codeproject.cachefly.net/Articles/12342/Drag-and-Drop-Listbox-Items-using-OLE